# how to get the value of a div, add characters to it, then send the formated value to nother div in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to first getting the value of a div, then adding character such as (+,-,%) to the value where there are spaces. Once done, I then need to set this value on another div. Is this possible to do in jquery. Is this possible to do i am a little confused.

Currently I can get the value of a div using:

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
$("#btn1").click ( function () {
alert ( $(".eventLocation").html() );
});

});
```

alert is used to check that I actually get the value of . This works fine, but then I am not too sure on how to add the characters if the value has spaces. For example if the value in the div is "RH3 3HF" then the character "+" has to be added where the space is so in between "RH3" and "3HF". Then this formatted value has to be to another div.

Any suggestion on this will be greatly appreciated as I am not too sure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do what you need...

```
var text = $("#Div1").text();//get the text of the first DIV
text = text.trim();//trim the text to remove any leading and trailing whitespace
text = text.replace(/\s/g, "+");//replace all whitespace values with a "+"
$("#Div2").text(text);//set the text value of the second DIV
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NLWn5/1/)

**Based on your comments...**

Assuming that Div1 only has one link you can do this to get the href value...

```
var href = $("#Div1 A").attr("href");
$("#Div2").html('<iframe scr=' + href + '></iframe>');
```

Comment: this a great example, now lastly before setting the text value to the second div, how would i then put the text value inside of an <iframe>? would something like this work? $("#DIV2").append('<iframe scr=' + text + '></iframe>'); ???? Thanks

Comment: you could just do... `$("#Div2").html('<iframe scr=' + text + '></iframe>');`

Comment: thanks that makes sense. lastly in case the first div contains a link which it will "<a href="www.google.com">sample link</a>" how would i get rid of the text "sample link" and also the beginning and ending tags for a href so only keeping www.google.com. so that this can be set inside the iframe tag of the second div??? Maybe this is what i should of asked to begin with... Thanks

Comment: @DanielPerez: Yes, you probably should have asked that. See my edited answer

Comment: The a href wont be empty, ie with will be the following <a href="www.google.com">Go to Google</a>. Can the text "Go to Google" be stripped out to make the link work when its set to the second div inside the iframe src tag??? Is this required, or will it work as is... Thanks

Comment: @DanielPerez: You have lost me now. Please give a final example of what you want the full HTML inside the IFrame to be

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myText = $('.myDiv').html();
myText.replace(" ", "yourCharacterHere");

$('.myOtherDiv').html(myText);
```

just remember that `.html` can also contain tags such as `<a>` and `<p>` etc

Comment: How does that help replacing whitespaces with "+" characters?

Comment: Ah my bad, I made my solution to your title :/

Comment: It is not my title ;) and your replace with only replace the first space character and not any subsequent ones - you need to do a Regex with the global flag (g)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that give suggestions I managed to get this working as follows:

```
var text = $(".eventLocation").text();//get the text of the first DIV
text = text.trim();//trim the text to remove any leading and trailing whitespace
text = text.replace(/\s/g, "+");//replace all whitespace values with a "+"

$(".eventMap").append('<iframe width="190px" height="180px" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&
amp;hl=en&amp;ttype=&amp;q=' + text + '&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;output=embed&amp;&iwloc=near">
</iframe>');
```